# NodeJs, does asynchronous function complete after api route has returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

My local tests find that the question is true.

Given the following code, where 'asyncOne' and 'asyncTwo' are asynchronous functions, if 'asyncTwo' completes before 'asyncOne' does 'asyncOne' still get time to finish execution?

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {

       asyncOne(function () {
            console.log("Completed asyncOne");
       });


       asyncTwo(function () {
            console.log("Completed asyncTwo");

            return res.json("Done.");
       });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes all code will execute. But you cannot `return res.json("Done.");` in the `asyncOne` function, because a end response has already been sent.

If you would like a return to be called when both async functions are done you should checkout the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module. It's really great.

Comment: Awesome, thankyou for confirming. I won't ever be returning from the asyncOne function :)

Comment: Just remember that it is possible that on of the two functions will finish before the other and that means you cannot pass the data from one function to the other, unless you use the async module :) Also don't forget to accept the answer if it is solved for you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you shoud call your functions like this:

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  Promise.all[asyncOne(), asyncTwo()].then(() => {
     return res.json("Done.");
  });
});
```

or like this:

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  asyncOne(function () {
   console.log("Completed asyncOne");
    asyncTwo(function () {
     console.log("Completed asyncTwo");
     return res.json("Done.");
    });
   });       
 });
```

Comment: Both valid approaches that I use elsewhere in my codebase, for this use-case though I don't care about waiting for the first function to complete, basically if it doesn't complete then I don't care so don't want it to affect the response time :)